# Using virtualenv and error message: - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

There has been quite a few installations of Python and Anacondas on my Mac over the years, and to some extent these have been neglected and I suspect now resurface and cause me issues.

I'd like to setup a **virtualenv** environment and did a **pip install virtualenv**. I'd like to create a new environement, **Django18**, for Django1.8, but after executing the command **virtualenv Django18** I receive an error message:

```
OSError: Command ~/Desktop/Django18/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

**bash_profile**

```
# added by Anaconda2 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

**command: which python**

```
~/anaconda2/bin/python
```

**In /usr/bin/:**

```
-rwxr-xr-x     2 root   wheel     58416 Jul 15  2015 python
-rwxr-xr-x     5 root   wheel       925 Sep 10  2014 python-config
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        75 Nov  9  2014 python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        82 Nov  9  2014 python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        75 Nov  9  2014 python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        82 Nov  9  2014 python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x     2 root   wheel     58416 Jul 15  2015 pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        76 Nov  9  2014 pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        76 Nov  9  2014 pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

**.profile**

```
export PATH="/opt/local/lib/gmt4/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="~/teqc:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/runpkr000:$PATH"
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-04-02_at_16:40:23: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
# export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
# export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

I suspect there needs to be some clearing up with this, but how can I resolve this error message and get **virtualenv** to work as expected? I have tried several methods already out there, but it's difficult for me to recognise what exactly in my case is causing this issue, before applying a potential remedy.

---

**/opt/local/bin (is that macports installation)?:**

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       24 Oct  9  2016 python -> /opt/local/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       31 Oct  9  2016 python-config -> /opt/local/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       73 Dec 14  2014 python2.7 -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       80 Dec 14  2014 python2.7-config -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       25 Oct  9  2016 pythonw -> /opt/local/bin/pythonw2.7
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin       74 Dec 14  2014 pythonw2.7 -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

**/usr/Local/bin**

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        69 Dec 12  2012 python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        72 Dec 12  2012 python3-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3-32
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        76 Dec 12  2012 python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        71 Dec 12  2012 python3.3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        74 Dec 12  2012 python3.3-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3-32
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        78 Dec 12  2012 python3.3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        72 Dec 12  2012 python3.3m -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3m
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        79 Dec 12  2012 python3.3m-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3m-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        70 Dec 12  2012 pythonw3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pythonw3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        73 Dec 12  2012 pythonw3-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pythonw3-32
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        72 Dec 12  2012 pythonw3.3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pythonw3.3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff        75 Dec 12  2012 pythonw3.3-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pythonw3.3-32
```

**import sys
sys.path**

```
~/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.6-py2.7.egg
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa
~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg
```

**/opt/local/Library/Frameworks:**

```
Python.framework
```

**/System/Library/Frameworks**

```
Python.framework
```

---

**EDIT**

`which python` produces :

```
~/anaconda2/bin/python
```

`which -a python` produces :

```
~/anaconda2/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

They're not the same. But then after deleting python installations in:

```
/opt/local/bin
/usr/Local/bin
/usr/bin
```

and using `rm -rf python*` and `sudo rm -rf python*` in

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks
```

the `which` outputs then become the same.

I've realised that the `which python` command actually refers to what is written in the `.bash_profile` file and not `.profile` (priority to .bash_profile).

In any case I commented out the `$PATH` in my `.bash_profile`, so forcing the environment variables only to be used in the `.profile` file. Then `source ~/.bash_profile`.

In my `.profile` I added:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages:$PATH
```

Then `source ~/.profile`

However after `which python` I still get:

```
~/anaconda2/bin/python
```

This is getting a bit frustrating as even changing the relevant files and deleting certain python installations, the result is still the same :-/

Comment: Anaconda comes with a command line tool called 'conda' which makes managing virtual environments alot easier. Have you tried `conda create -n <env_name> python=3.6`? (replace `3.6` with the python version of your choice). Environments created with conda will be installed to `<anaconda_path>/envs/<env_name>` by default.

Answer (score 2):

For me the best workaround was to check first in `which -a python`, in my case there are two occurrences:

```
~/anaconda2/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

For some unknown reason, the `virtualenv` command doesn't seem to like the anaconda installation of python, so use instead:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 my_environment
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but then i just realized that i was trying to create a virtualenv folder (C:/myname/virtual_folder) at the same **directory level** as was my Python installation folder (C:/myname/python27) .

So I just created a folder and then inside of it (C:/myname/newfolder/..) i run ("virtualenv virtual_folder") with no issues .

Answer (score 0):

If you have several disparate installations for python and anaconda, th only thing I can recommend is to just clean up. But also interested what other will tell.

Comment: Cleaning up is what I thought, but I assume it's just not a simple case of delete the Python version that I don't want? Are there other locations too where it is installed...that's also not clear.

Comment: not a simple case, sure :) because you probably installed diff. dependencies with diff. clients at diff. locations. I found two posts on SO how to do clean up:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909249/how-to-clean-up-my-python-installation-for-a-fresh-start
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117945/too-many-different-python-versions-on-my-system-and-causing-problems

Comment: I looked in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks & /System/Library/Frameworks & sys.path & /usr/Local/bin & /opt/local/bin as there are loads more Python installations. NB: Just edited original post. It seems /opt/local/bin could be Macports? Which directories are recommended to delete (what is the normal procedure to remove installations from a directory)? Why is there no $PYTHONPATH ? I assume too from the other threads that nothing from /opt/local/Library/Frameworks nor /System/Library/Frameworks should be deleted, but why is there two instances of Python.framework in these directories?